# Audio recording on Ubuntu Phone Aquaris E4.5

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-touch, audio-recording

I cannot find any software for recording audio on Ubuntu Phone. It is a most usefull feature for musicians, authors and interviewers. Video just don't do the trick, taking up too much space and not being so easy to name and organize.

Any suggestions how to get arourd this? I tried to find some software for sending audio messages but no luck there. It is a necessary feature for me and so I've had to continue using my Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solutions provided in this forum topic:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2276546

According to the comments in the Ubuntu App Store soundtrap doesn't work on the Aquarius, so you're left only with the terminal solution for now.

**//EDIT:**

I also found this thing but it seems it's only source code and you'll have to compile it yourself - http://stefano92100.blogspot.com/p/audiotape.html

**//EDIT 2:**

There seems to be a new app designated for this purpose. It si called 'recorder' and it can be downloaded from the app store.
https://uappexplorer.com/app/recorder.pramathesh

Comment: Thanks! Terminal is working, though not sure how to view the files I've recorded. Can't see them in file manager. Also mono-quality has a lot of background noice.

Comment: @Aslak  - in case you're still looking for an app check out the second edit to my answer.